# How add Select as first value to a database populated combobox in asp windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
SqlConnection con = getConnection();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(storedprocedureName, con);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
da.Fill(DS);
stateDropDownList.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
stateDropDownList.ValueMember = "STATE_ID";
stateDropDownList.DisplayMember = "STATE_NAME";
```

This data source is returning state details and i have attached the satedetails datasource into combobox.

i want to display the combobox with first item select and rest as all states.

i googled it a lot for dropdown list there are codes but nothing showing ...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the same way as Drop Down list:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

Entire code:

```
SqlConnection con = getConnection();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(storedprocedureName, con);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
da.Fill(DS);
ComboBox1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "STATE_ID";
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "STATE_NAME";
ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

Comment: so how i add in case i need to add one datasource also to combobox